# How to use crypto on both browsers and nodejs inside a js script

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I try to use the crypto API and specifically the randomUUID function. They are both available in NodeJS and browser environments, so it can be used in Nuxt 3.

However, importing them both in this script is hard. How do you make this work?

Here is a try:

```js
// @ts-ignore(TS2304) as the window will only be defined on the browser
const crypto = (typeof process !== "undefined") ? require('crypto'): window.crypto

export const useId = () => {
  const suffix = crypto.randomUUID().slice(0, 8)
  const $id = (name?: string) => name ? `${name}-${suffix}` : suffix
  return { $id }
}
```

In the end, I get the error `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: global is not defined` in the browser. It works fine on NodeJS.

Comment: A workaround for now is to use `Date.now() + ((Math.random() * 100000).toFixed()) ` but it still has a risk.

Comment: Is this a composable?

I think that the issue comes from the fact that `window` is available on the browser only after it is mounted.

This will work:
```vue
<script setup>
  const uuid = ref(null);
  onMounted(() => {
    uuid.value = window.crypto.randomUUID().slice(0, 8);
  });
</script>
```

This one will not: 
```vue
<script setup>
  const uuid = window.crypto.randomUUID().slice(0, 8);
</script>
```
Can you show some code on how you are trying to it on the server and on the browser?

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 enviroments because `process` can be:

1. `undefined`
2. `server`
3. `client`

When it is undefined, you can use `crypto`.

When it is `client`, you can use `window.crypto`.

But when is `server`, by default, you can't use either: in fact, `window` is not available before the browser is mounted and crypto can't be imported because [vite does not polyfill Node.js modules to reduce the bundle size](https://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#module-externalized-for-browser-compatibility).

With your code, you are trying to use `window.crypto` both on `process.server` and `process.client`, which is not possible.

A workaround is to use [vite-plugin-node-polyfills](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-node-polyfills) package and exclude all the modules except `crypto` to keep the bundle size smaller.

To use it run:

```
npm install --save-dev vite-plugin-node-polyfills
```

And in your `nuxt.config.js` add:

```js
  vite: {
    plugins: [
      nodePolyfills({
        exclude: [
          'assert',
          'buffer',
          'child_process',
          'cluster',
          'dgram',
          'dns',
          'domain',
          'events',
          'fs',
          'http',
          'https',
          'net',
          'os',
          'path',
          'punycode',
          'querystring',
          'readline',
          'stream',
          'string_decoder',
          'timers',
          'tls',
          'tty',
          'url',
          'util',
          'v8',
          'vm',
          'zlib',
        ],
        globals: {
          Buffer: true,
          global: true,
          process: true,
        },
        protocolImports: true,
      }),
    ],
  },
```

Now you can use `import crypto from 'crypto'` both when you are on process `undefined` or `server` and `window.crypto` when you are on `process.client`.

I'm not sure all this is worth if it just to generate a uuid. If that is the only use you need, you can use a package like [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) that can be used everywhere by default.